# How can I recover photos from Photo Stream to my computer?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photo-stream

My iPhone's screen decided to die on me, so the screen is black, and I got a Samsung to replace it. The problem is that I can't get anything off of my phone. I did back up to my iCloud but how I am going to get all of my photos that I saved on iCloud?

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent, could you please add more relevant information about your issue? This is a bit vague regarding the *export and only 3 numbers*

Comment: The site works best when there is only one question per question — I've edited out the second question, feel free to ask it separately if you can't find an existing answer.

Comment: What OS runs on your computer?

Answer (score 1):

As this is tagged [photo-stream](/questions/tagged/photo-stream) I presume that you 'backed up' to Photo Stream. You can recover the photos from your Photo Stream by opening the Photo Stream on your computer.

```
~/Library/Application Support/iLifeAssetManagement/assets/sub
```

Inside this folder are all the photos from your Photo Stream. Copy them to your new phone.